# Using VB Redim Preserve equivalent for multi-dimemsional array in C#

Tags: c#

I need to translate the next VB code in something equivalent of C#:

```
Dim M() As Variant, M1 As Variant, i As Long, El As Variant, k As Long
 M1 = GetAllChildrenWindowHandlesA(CLngPtr(723126), 100): k = 1
 ReDim M(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
 For i = 1 To 20
    M(1, i) = "x" & i: M(2, i) = M1: M(3, i) = i
    k = k + 1: ReDim Preserve M(1 To 3, 1 To k)
 Next i
 Debug.Print UBound(M()), LBound(M())
 ReDim Preserve M(1 To 3, 1 To k - 1)
 For Each El In M(2, 5)
    k = k - 1
    Debug.Print El, M(1, k), M(3, k)
 Next
```

So I need something able to keep three different variable types (string, array, int), but connected between each other in order to have the possibility of identifying which string corresponds to array (or to int) on the same level. In the above case to be able to determine the M(1, k) or M(2, k) for identified k searching the array...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't use `:` whitespace is your friend. Not sure what (if anything) the answer is but I suspect that you'd have a hell of a lot easier time using 0-based array indexing

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing / translating service. If you've tried something and are having difficulty, show that. The question in your title doesn't correlate with the question at the end of the body. You should try and reword what your specific problem is

Comment: I have a server C# application able to keep in a listView multiple connections of Corel dockers (C#). I am trying to collect all child and sub child windows in a treeView. I want to use for that a recursive method which should use the mentioned approach. Since I am not experienced in C# I already did it in Corel VBA and now I am trying to find a way to use it in C#. The code above is just a sample test used by me in VBA in order to figure out the basis of the used algorithm. I would post C# if I would know what is good to be use instead of VBA solution. I use ':' in order to condense the code.

Answer (score 0):

To create a 3x20 object matrix that's 1 based, that can be done like this:

```
Object[,] M = (Object[,]) Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), new int[]{3,20}, new int[]{1,1});
```

As far as I know, there isn't an easy way in C# to replicate a ReDim Preserve for multidimensional arrays. I think you'd have to create a new array each time and use the Array.Copy method to copy the elements over. That being said, I believe you'd be better off using A_J's List<> suggestion with a structure or class:

```
struct MData
{
  public string M1;
  public IntPtr[] M2;
  public int M3;
}
```

and then something like this:

```
        IntPtr[] childHandles = GetAllChildrenWindowHandlesA(new IntPtr(723126),100);

        List<MData> M = new List<MData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < childHandles.Length; i++)
        {
            M.Add(new MData() { 
                  M1 = "x" + i.ToString()
                , M2 = childHandles 
                , M3 = i
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I am new in C# I would need some more clarification about using the structure and list, as following: How can I add many such three sequences in the list? And how can I iterate between the list elements in order to use M1 when I found M3? I mean searching for all M3 elements and returning M1 for the found one.

Comment: I played with your structure list suggestion and it works like a charm. Thanks again!